# why my Javascript doesn't load from the beginning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, runtime-error

I am a newbie to web development and I am trying to create a portfolio project for practice. My problem is that every time i reload the page it's like the js code load slow and the page shows some elements from the second page and then upload the js script.

```js
$('#slides').superslides({
    animation: 'fade',
    play: 5000,
    pagination: false
});

var typed = new Typed(".typed", {
    strings: ["Computer Engineer.", "Data Scientist."],
    typeSpeed: 90,
    loop: false,
    startDelay: 1000,
    showCursor: false
});
```

I upload the code on http://jsfiddle.net/L34re768/5/ also i copy paste the superslides library that i use because the jsfiddle doesn't recognize it. I like to mention that this is not my first project that happen something like that, it happen again with other library of js. Any help please.

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: i have upload it on jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/L34re768/5/

Comment: Your problem is not that JS doesn't load from the beginning, the initial "state" of the page is not what you want.  Sometimes JS might take additional time to fetch some elements, and your function is set to fire when the page is ready, but the page will display even before is completely ready, a good design will show nicely before the JS kicks in, sometimes that means modifying your HTML to simulate the initial state, or maybe adding a "loading" element on top of everything by default and then removing it with JS. Remove the call to superslides and style that DOM first., then add it back.